# Dynamic query (in stored procedure) based on params provided (SQL Server 2016)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I have an employee table that has over 30 columns. This table is exposed by a web service via a stored procedure that returns all users.

I need to create a new stored procedure that allows you to search on 6 specific columns. I have those columns as input params for the stored procedure, but I am unsure how to create a query that only uses the params that were passed.

For example:

```
exec SearchUsers @firstName = 'John', @department = 'Admin'
```

should perform a query only those columns. However, there are 5 available params that can be passed in.

Here are my parameters

```
@lastName nvarchar(255) = '',
@firstName nvarchar(255)  = '',
@office nvarchar(50)  = '',
@department nvarchar(50)  = '',
@language nvarchar(255)  = '',
@jobTitle nvarchar(255) = '',
```

I want to build a query that is dynamic enough to only query the values provided.

Comment: Read: http://sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: Thank you, this was a huge help in understanding each option.

Answer (score 0):

On the where clause, beyond your normal condition, for each param you just have to add a condition `OR @param1 IS NULL`. So if the param is null, the whole condition will be "ignored" since it will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

So you can change your parameters to be 'null' by default

```
@lastName nvarchar(255) = null,
@firstName nvarchar(255)  = null,
@office nvarchar(50)  = null,
@department nvarchar(50)  = null,
@language nvarchar(255)  = null,
@jobTitle nvarchar(255) = null,
```

Then in your where clause, check for the existence of NULL before comparing the value to the corresponding field.

```
where (@lastName is null or lastname = @lastName)
and (@firstName is null or firstName = @firstName)
and (@office is null or office = @office)
and (@department is null or department = @department)
and (@language is null or language = @language)
and (@jobTitle is null or jobTitle = @jobTitle)
```

Answer (score 0):

here a example :

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchUsers] ( 

@lastName Varchar(255) = '',
@firstName Varchar(255)  = '',
@office Varchar(50)  = '',
@department Varchar(50)  = '',
@language Varchar(255)  = '',
@jobTitle Varchar(255) = ''

AS

Set Nocount On

Select lastname,firstname,office,departament,language,jobtitle From Users (Nolock)
Where
lastname Like Case When @lastName <> '' Then @lastName Else lastname End
And firstname Like Case When @firstName <> '' Then @firstName Else firstname End
And office Like Case When @office <> '' Then @office Else office End
And departament Like Case When @department <> '' Then @department Else departament End
And language Like Case When @jobTitle <> '' Then @jobTitle Else jobtitle End

Set Nocount Off


exec SearchUsers @firstName = 'John', @department = 'Admin'
```